# code iterating through a foreach loop 84 times, unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a section of code and everything seems to be working correctly so far, but for some reason I have a foreach loop that is iterating 84 times before ending. I want to add more code to the loop to move the tile that I am iterating over, but it runs the movement code 84 times and throws it off the world coordinates.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 0f;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePos);

        clickedX = boardScript.RoundToScale(mousePos.x);
        clickedY = boardScript.RoundToScale(mousePos.y);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        boardScript.movingLeft = false;
        boardScript.movingRight = false;
        boardScript.movingUp = false;
        boardScript.movingDown = false;
        tempList.Clear ();

        //This is the foreach loop that is iterating 84 times
        foreach (TileInfo tile in tileInfo) {
            if (tile.tileLocation.y == clickedY) {
                Vector3 clickedLocation = tile.tileObject.transform.position;
                Debug.Log ("we landed at: " + clickedLocation.x + ", " + clickedLocation.y);
            }
        }

        return;
    } 

    if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
            return;
        }
        float mouseMoveX = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
        float mouseMoveY = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y");

        if (mouseMoveX < 0) {
            boardScript.movingLeft = true;
            boardScript.movingRight = false;
        }

        if (mouseMoveX > 0) {
            boardScript.movingLeft = false;
            boardScript.movingRight = true;
        }

        foreach (TileInfo tile in tileInfo) {
            if (tile.tileLocation.y == clickedY) {
                tile.tileObject.transform.Translate (mouseMoveX, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any other sections of code or anything else let me know, I'm new at this and still learning.

Edit: clarified the question I was asking.

Edit2: added a link to the debug log that I have in the loop to show exactly what is happening.

[image: command log]

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What's the length of `tileInfo`?

Comment: "that is throwing some errors with code that I want to add" What code are you trying to add and what errors (specifically) does this cause. At the moment, all we can say is that you have 84 items in `tileInfo`, but that's probably not what you want to know.

Comment: length of tileInfo is 84, even though that is the same it shouldn't be iterating the same number of times.

Comment: Also for instance the debug.log statement is read 84 times * 7 which is the number of times that the if statement is true

Comment: What I want to do next is move the exact tile to a predetermined location, however since the loop iterates so many times, the tile gets thrown off the screen out of the world coordinates.

Comment: you have to ***COPY AND PASTE IN THE ERRORS***, my man!  click "Edit" just below your question to do so.

Comment: well there are no errors, just errors in the sense that it is breaking the code. So I cannot just copy and paste them. Like I explained in the comment right above yours, when I add more code to the foreach loop it runs it 84 times. I want to move the tile that I am iterating over and instead it throws it off the screen since the movement is multiplied so many times.

Comment: Update your Debug.Log to include the gameObject.name of the tile as well.... My guess is that you have 84 tiles and each tile is passing your if statement so you get 84 identical log messages. Adding the gameObject.name (assuming the names are unique) will show you what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, so I had this script attached to every single tile object in the game. So everything in the script would run 84 times since there were 84 tiles being created.

Thanks for the the help all!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your foreach in Update and this not work only 1 time, this work each frame. But 84 times is a very high number for this.
You can use a single flag to control and only run 1 time.

```
    doLoop = true;

    if (doLoop)
    {
     doLoop = false;
     //my loop script
    }
```

Comment: that did not fix the issue, it still iterates over the loop 84 times for each true statement.

Comment: if your TileInfo lenght is 84, is right that the foreach code run 84 time. You need to fix your condition to do what you need or not.